# How to get Str() to left align in MS Access 2013

Tags: string, ms-access, ms-access-2013

Using the built in evaluation function Str() to convert a number to a string the resultant number seems to come with a preceding space which is messing with my report formatting.  Entries with numbers indent slightly relative to those without.  Is there a simple solution to this - or even a complicated one?

Example: Calculated field using:

```
IIf([NumNights]=1,"Wibble",Str([NumNights])+" nights")
```

Produces (in the table, but also on any report using this):

[image]

Comment: Take a look at trim().

Comment: @D.Mika - perfect, thanks. Would you like to add that as an answer please, so I can credit it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at trim():

```
Trim(Str([NumNights]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use CStr:

```
IIf([NumNights]=1,"Wibble",CStr([NumNights])+" nights")
```

Comment: Unfortunately CStr() isn't available in the Aceess 2013 Expression Builder.  Admittedly I didn't say that's what I was using, and this would be fine for any other case.